# Encryption and decryption with Serpent using Crypto++ and Bouncy Castle?

Tags: ios, encryption, bouncycastle, crypto++

I need to build an app on windows/mac using Java and separate apps native on IOS and Android for encrypting with Serpent.

I implemented using Bouncy Castle on Java for win/mac and with Crypto++ on iOS, but what I encrypt with Bouncy Castle cannot be decrypted with Crypto++ or the other way around.

Does anyone know why Bouncy Castle and Crypto++ are not inter-oping?

Thank you!

Comment: The cipher is *very* likely compatible between BouncyCastle and Crypto++. This is either an encoding problem or a mode/padding problem. Please create two [MCVEs](/help/mcve) for Java and Crypto++ to compare the results. Don't forget to add some example inputs, outputs and expected outputs. You can [edit] your question to include the missing information.

Comment: On iOS there is a hardware crypto engine that supports AES and is much faster, 500 to 1000 times faster, than code-only AES, I would expect the similar results for Serpent. IMO you need a very good reason to use Serpent over AES.

Answer (score 2):

With BC you need to use the version at http://www.bouncycastle.org/betas It turns out the NESSIE vectors in fact define the correct input/output ordering. The AES submission had them reversed.

If it's any help the AES submission where implemented is now called Tnepres, only versions compliant with the NESSIE vectors are called Serpent. The 1.54 beta of BC offers both Tnepres and Serpent. Unfortunately, due to a misunderstanding between BC and the Serpent authors, BC 1.53 and earlier in fact implements Tnepres.